# Resize/Hide charts in Multi pane in Highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I want to **Resize/Hide**, **Lower/Upper** charts in `Multi pane highcharts`

My sample chart is given on that link [Js-Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/vgrh0x55/3/)

I have identified `Resize` property and able to resize panes only left to hide chats, Please help/suggest to achieving.

Comment: Is this topic solved?

Comment: Partially solved but still not hide lower part of chart and axis.

Comment: So what you're trying to achieve is when one of the series is hidden the container should be resized to a smaller size so that the visible series takes the whole plot area space?

Comment: Yes, you are right.I want exactly same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a part of the solution to hide (not resize)

```
...
// the button action - Line 96
var $button = $('#Hide');
$button.click(function () {
    var upperSeries = chart.series[0];
    if (upperSeries.visible) {
        upperSeries.hide();
    } else {
        upperSeries.show();
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgrh0x55/5/)

Answer (score 2):

Refer to this **live demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/8vtcznf7/

When the button is clicked container and chart need to be resized:

```
container.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
chart.setSize(undefined, newHeight);
```

After the chart is resized axes' properties need to be changed so that the first series takes the whole plot area space:

```
bottomSeries.yAxis.update({
  height: '100%',
  top: '0%'
});

upperSeries.yAxis.update({
  visible: false
});
```